# Use push and pop to reverse and print out an array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, reverse

Trying a few lines of code to **manually reverse** an array by character and print it out. (yes, i know this can be done by the reverse function).

To begin with, I have a dummy file called dummy.txt

```
abcdefg1234567890
```

My perl script here:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = 'dummy.txt';
my @reverse_array;

open (FH, '<', $file)
    or die ("Couldn't open $file : $!");

#split with empty string to get individual characters
my @chars = split("", <FH>); 

print "$#chars\n"; #prints 16, meaning there are 17 elements in @chars
print "@chars\n";  #prints a b c d e f g 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0

for(my $i=0; $i <= $#chars; $i++) #iterate number of elements' times
{
    push @reverse_array, pop @chars; #pop the elements out of @chars into @reverse_array
}

print "$#reverse_array \n"; #prints 8, meaning there are 9 elements in @reverse_array
print "@reverse_array \n";  #prints 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2, not as expected, but this is indeed 17 elements including the white space

close (FH)
    or die ("Failed to close $file: $!");
```

So **pop** is popping out whitespaces. So **split** is adding white spaces when I try to split it with empty string?  I'm still thinking how to get around this. Would love your input, and modify on my code would be be best for me.

Comment: Another question I have is,  when printing,  why $#reverse_array NOT treats whitespace as an element to the array,  while  @reverse_array DO treats whitespace as an element?

Comment: Think about what happens to `$#chars` as you `pop` elements off the end of `@chars`.

Comment: You have `use Data::Dumper` in your code. If you had dumped the contents of the array with `print Dumper \@reverse_array` you would be able to see the true contents

Answer (score 4):

It is always preferable to iterate over a list in Perl, rather than using the ugly C-style for loop

Your loop

```
for (my $i=0; $i <= $#chars; $i++) {
    push @reverse_array, pop @chars;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
my $i = 0;
while ( $i <= $#chars ) {
    push @reverse_array, pop @chars;
    ++$i;
}
```

so `$#chars` starts at 16. The loop is executed once, and now `$i` is 1 while `$#chars` is 15 because of the `pop`. This process will continue until after the eighth iteration of the loop -- when `$i` is 8 and `$#chars` is 7, and the test now fails so the loop exits

This has the effect that you are reversing only the last eight elements of `@chars`, as you have seen

If instead you write

```
for my $i ( 0 .. $#chars ) {
    push @reverse_array, pop @chars;    
}
```

then it's not only clearer and easier to read, but it also does what you intend

The whitespace comes from Perl's behaviour when *stringifying* arrays. If you write `"@array\n"` then Perl builds a string containing the elements of `@array`, separated by a single space. (This is the default behaviour. You can change the string used to separate the elements, but I advise you don't go there yet.)

To print just the contents of the array then you can write

```
print @chars, "\n"
```

and you will see what you expect

Comment: Alternately, although kind of golfy:  `push @reverse_array, pop @chars while @chars;`

Comment: `map` could be appropriate too since you are doing a transformation of sorts: `my @reverse_array = map { pop @chars } 0 .. $#chars;`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: You're both missing the point. The way to write this is `my @reverse_array = reverse @chars`. The exercise is a theoretical one

Comment: @Borodin I don't think I was. The only constraints on the problem were to use `push` and `pop`, I was simply suggesting that `map` was a reasonable alternative to `for`

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Others here think the only constraint is *not* to use `reverse`. I thought all the OP was after was a cleanup of his own code, but only he knows for sure

Comment: @Borodin Excellent explanation. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're using `$#chars` in your loop construct, and it's changing as you go. You need to save it first:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

my @reversed;
my @chars = split //, $str;

my $elt_count = scalar @chars;

for ( 1 .. $elt_count ) {
    push( @reversed, pop @chars );
}

print @reversed;
```

But you could tackle it a little more easily with a `while` loop:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

my @reversed;
my @chars = split //, $str;

while ( @chars ) {
    push( @reversed, pop @chars );
}

print @reversed;
```

Which relies on the fact that you're emptying `@chars` as you go, and bails out when there's nothing left.

You should also be aware - there's a difference between:

```
print "@reversed";
```

and

```
print @reversed;
```

In the former case, perl is inserting spaces because you've converted the array to  a string. That's why you're getting the apparent behaviour that your are.